# Problem connecting AWS Textract and S3 storage to run aynchronous operation on PDF files. Getting error "InvalidS3ObjectException"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-textract

Have gone through and activated an IAM role with access to Textract, SNS, and S3. When attempting to run start_document_text_detection, getting met with an error saying "InvalidS3ObjectException" and Textract is unable to access S3 object.

Both S3 and Textract are initialized in the same region, and my credentials have no problems downloading files from the S3 bucket.

This is being run in a Jupyter notebook written in Python.

Can anyone give some insight as to what issues may be causing this hangup? Would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Any code you can provide?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.